# Sum of Catalan numbers

Tags: combinatorics, catalan-numbers

What is $C_1 +C_2 + C_3 +... + C_n$, where each $C_i$ is Catalan number? 
I want to know if we can bound this sum by some function of $n$. I am looking for an upper bound.
For sure it is less than $2^{2n}$.
Can we say it is less than $2^{\log_2(2n)}=2n$?

Comment: This is [OEIS A014138](http://oeis.org/A014138); according to that entry, the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ partial sum is asymptotically $\frac{2^{2n+2}}{3\sqrt{\pi}\cdot n^{3/2}}$.

Comment: $C_n$ is way bigger than $2n$ so it looks really impossible to me that the sum of the first $n$ Catalan numbers is bounded by $2n$.

Answer (score 8):

By exploiting the [integral representation of Catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number):
$$ C_n = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{4}x^n\sqrt{\frac{4-x}{x}}\,dx = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}4^n x^n\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{x}}\,dx$$
we have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}S_N=\sum_{n=1}^{N}C_n &=& \frac{8}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-4^N x^N}{1-4x}\sqrt{x(1-x)}\,dx.\end{eqnarray*}$$
By computing the derivative of the integrand function it is straightforward to check that $f_N(x)=\frac{1-4^N x^N}{1-4x}\sqrt{x(1-x)}$ attains its maximum near:
$$ x = \frac{5N-1+\sqrt{9N^2-18N+1}}{8N}=1-\frac{1}{2N}-\frac{1}{6N^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{N^3}\right)$$
hence it is possible to approximate $S_N$ by computing the values of $f_N(x)$ and $f_N''(x)$ in the stationary point $x_N$, just like it is usual in the saddle point method. We have:
$$ f_N(x)\leq\frac{4^N}{\sqrt{eN}} $$
$$ f_N''(x_N)=-\frac{4^{N+1}\sqrt{2}}{3\sqrt{e}}N^{3/2}\left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\right)\right)$$
hence:

> $$\color{blue}{ S_N \leq \frac{20\cdot 4^N}{9\sqrt{e\pi}\,N^{3/2}}.}$$

Comment: Could you refer from where you get the integral representation of Catalan numbers?

Comment: It just follows from the generating functions for Catalan numbers, anyway I just found it on the Wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number

Comment: Oh! How could I miss it? Thanks!